# Variable/uneven number of items in a Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a grid that gets populated from a CMS. I don't know if the number of items will be odd or even. The design calls for 3 columns on the desktop

[image]

and 2 columns on mobile devices

[image]

with the last item centered if there is only one.
The only way I have found to do this is by programmatically checking the number of items and using `col-xs-6` for the last of an even set or `col-xs-12` for the last of an odd set.

```
<div class="row partners">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Our Partners.</h1>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="images/headshot.jpg" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="images/headshot.jpg" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="images/headshot.jpg" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this without programming logic. It would be nice if Bootstrap had "greedy" columns that fill out remaining columns of the grid if they are not used?

Answer (score 0):

Floats don't like to center so the a good way to approach this would be to use inline block instead

Add a "centered" class to the row:

```
<div class="row partners centered">
```

And modify the way columns work:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.centered > div {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/d2gcf39w/

---

Also note that the Bootstrap container hierarchy is Container > Row > Col so the first two lines in your example should be swapped:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row partners centered">
        <h1>Our Partners.</h1>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="headshot-wrapper">
                <p><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" /></p>
            </div>
            <h2>Partnername</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```